# Sort mixed alpha/numeric Array in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

#### I have a mixed array that I need to sort by digit and then by alphabet

```
var x = ['1','2A','2B','2AA','2','10A','10','11','12A','12B','12']
```

> Desired Output

```
sortedArray = ['1','2','2A','2B','2AA','10','10A','11','12','12A','12B']
```

#### I had tried using lodash but wasn't getting desired result

```
var x = ['1','2A','2B','2AA','2','10A','10','11','12A','12B','12']

_.sortBy(x);

//lodash result

 ["1", "10", "10A", "11", "12", "12A", "12B", "2", "2A", "2AA", "2B"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to get the number part and `sort` it. If both `a` and `b` have the same number, then sort them based their `length`. If they both have the same length, then sort them alphabetically using [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

```js
let array = ['1','2A','2B','2AA','2','10A','10','11','12A','12B','12'];

array.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a) - parseInt(b) 
                  || a.length - b.length 
                  || a.localeCompare(b));
                  
console.log(array)
```

Comment: needed 2AA after 2B refer the desired output above

Comment: @Snivio what is logic for putting `AA` after `B`?

Comment: `x.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a) - parseInt(b) || a.length - b.length || a.localeCompare(b));`

Comment: @PranavCBalan Thanks, I have added that. Your answer looks much more extensible.

Comment: @adiga : yours would be faster :)

Comment: @Snivio you can mark one of the [answers as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289255) by clicking on the grey checkmark on the left.

Answer (score 2):

You can use custom sot function, within custom function split digit and non-digit seperately and sort based on num and if both are equal compare the non-digit part.

```js
const arr = ['1', '2A', '2B', '2AA', '2', '10A', '10', '11', '12A', '12B', '12']

arr.sort((a, b) => {
  // extract digit and non-digit part from string
  let as = a.match(/(\d+)(\D*)/);
  let bs = b.match(/(\d+)(\D*)/);
  // either return digit differennce(for number based sorting)
  // in addition to that check string length(in case digits are same)
  // or compare non-digit part(string comparison)
  return as[1] - bs[1] || a.length - b.length ||as[2].localeCompare(bs[2]);
})

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: needed 2AA after 2B refer the desired output above

Comment: @Snivio  :compare the string length as well